# Redirecting to another page with JWT auth header in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, jwt, passport.js

I have a two module angularjs app. One module is handling authentication (login, register) and the second module is "chat" which  is protected in nodejs backend with passport-jwt strategy. Both modules have separate `index.html` files.
The authentication module have a `register()` method in register controller that looks like this:

```
$scope.register = function () {

         $http({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/api/register',
            data: {
                username: $scope.username,
                email: $scope.email,
                password: $scope.password
            },
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
```

(the `/api/register` route does all the register-related actions) and the `login()` method in login controller that looks like this:

```
 $scope.login = function () {
            $http({
                method: 'post',
                url: '/api/login',
                data: {
                    username: $scope.username,
                    password: $scope.password
                },
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }).then(function success(res) {
                //TODO redirection to '/chat' with auth token
            }
        };
```

If the user is in the database api sends back a jwt token which is available on res.body.token and should, using that token, get a secured chat page which is available on 'localhost:3000/chat' url. The problem is that i don't know how to send a proper request from angular client with a `Authorization` header containing the token to get that chat page.

Comment: Save token to localstorage or cookies then redirect to chat. Then in chat controller or component constructor get token and validate it. If it is not valid, redirect to authentication. If it is valid load the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an HTTP interceptor which will add the Bearer token in the request header-

```
// Injects an HTTP interceptor that replaces a "Bearer" authorization header with the current Bearer token.
module.factory('oauthHttpInterceptor', function (OAuth) {
  return {
    request: function (config) {      
      if (config.headers.Authorization === 'Bearer') {
        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + btoa(OAuth.accessToken);
      }
      return config;
    }
  };
});

module.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('oauthHttpInterceptor');
});
```